# PHP 7.1 "require/include" result is not up to date

Tags: php

I have a file containing:

```
<?php
    return '2000-01-01 00:00:00';
?>
```

and I have this code:

```
<?php

    $oldValue = require 'file.php';
    $now = new DateTime();
    $handle = fopen('file.php', "w");
    fputs($handle, "<?php\nreturn '" . $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "';");
    fclose($handle);
    $newValue = require 'file.php';

    echo "Old value: $oldValue ";
    echo "New value: $newValue ";
?>
```

The output with PHP 5.3 is:

```
Old value: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 New value: 2018-03-28 10:33:12
```

The output with PHP 7.1 is:

```
Old value: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 New value: 2000-01-01 00:00:00
```

In the two cases, the string in the file changes.

Can some one help me to update the new value with PHP 7.1?

Note: it's not the real problem. It's just an abstraction of the problem to make things more simple and comprehensible. So please, no lessons of [PHP best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/). I just like to get a good response to my question.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is _horrible_ style! The `require` statement is used to load additional class and function implementations. It is not meant as a cheap replacement for a function call.

Comment: @arkascha Tell laravel that

Comment: I had `Old value: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 New value: 2018-03-28 10:41:05` on my mac, PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09)

Comment: @Dale No, I won't. I just point out the objective fact. If someone chooses to use a framework doing such things, then sure, issues arise.

Comment: Thats not completely true @arkascha By definition, `include/require` loads and executes the file. It's totally fine, to use `return` statements with that. But yes, the general style is horrible. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr I never denied that, did I?

Comment: Yes, you told him that it's not _meant_ to use it like that. But in general, it is. @arkascha

Comment: @eisbehr I disagree. But that is fine, I guess.

Comment: @arkascha http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php example #5

Comment: Yes, it's fine. ;) I totally agree with you, that this is not the best idea and I would never use it like this. But the official docs (sadly) shows exactly that usage. @arkascha

Comment: @eisbehr Those docs also contain examples implementing html form definitions and the evaluation of the post request resulting from them in the same file. What does that tell us?

Comment: I have a problem bigger than this and I does not use return but juste to make a simple example I used this content and return

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a required file returning a variable - it's used all over the place. Dynamically rewriting and then re-requiring the same file in process on the other hand? That's deeply nasty. For reference, this is almost certainly an issue with the file being cached, either by PHP's opcache or your webserver. This is why it can't be replicated on the CLI

Comment: @scx No the content of the file changes

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko, I use PHP FPM

Comment: Note: it's not the real problem. It's just an abstraction of the problem to make things more simple and comprehensible. So please, no lessons of PHP best practices. I just like to get a response to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [**commented by iainn**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532269/php-7-1-require-result-is-not-up-to-date#comment86071159_49532269) The issue is that the PHP server is *caching* the file once it's loaded and is not re-calling the file from disc on the second require, instead calling it from it's memory cache.

As you have stated that:

> "the content of the file changes "

then the issue is the *new* contents are not passed to the script, instead using the *memory* of the older contents.

Therefore call [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) to force clear the cached file data. This should be placed after the new data is written to update the file, and before the file is called for a second time.

If this does not work then the file data may be cached elsewhere in its route.

```
<?php

    $oldValue = require 'file.php';
    $now = new DateTime();
    $handle = fopen('file.php', "w");
    fputs($handle, "<?php\nreturn '" . $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "';");
    fclose($handle);
    clearstatcache();           // THIS line should help you 
    $newValue = require 'file.php';

    echo "Old value: $oldValue ";
    echo "New value: $newValue ";
?>
```

---

- As [also commented by iainn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532269/php-7-1-require-result-is-not-up-to-date/49532881#comment86071930_49532881) `opcache_invalidate()`may be a more specific/less general solution for you.

Comment: I was just writing up an answer about using `opcache_invalidate('file.php');` instead, since it's a bit more directed. But yes, this is the general solution.

Comment: @iainn If you want to post your answer I am happy to link to it and `+1` you. It would be a more specific answer than my general ***kill all the caches!!!!*** approach

Comment: @martin, as I mentionned I have a bigger problem but to simplify things and to make things more comprehensible I used this abstract code. In my case it's impossible to use database :)

Comment: @T.AKROUT ok. That's fine. But using `clearstatcache()` should solve your immediate problem as described `:-)`

Comment: In my case opcache_invalidate() function resolves the problem thanks @Martin and iainn

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your file being cached ([OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php)) and php returning the same file in both require calls

Can you try modifying [opcache settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php)

```
opcache.enable = 0
```

and then testing it ? Also there is

```
opcache_reset()
```

could help you but if you running your code from CLI it may not work.

Comment: Thanks for your response but file content changes :)